# MapView and dealloc IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, android-mapview, dealloc

Hello i have a mapView and i think it takes too much memory after leaving the mapView

here are my methods is anything missing?

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{

    mapView.showsUserLocation = NO; b
    [mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations]; 

    [super viewDidUnload];

}


-(void)dealloc{
    [name release];
    [type release];
    [address release];
    mapView.delegate = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    foundLocation = location found <----   

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude = foundLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude=foundLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    region.span.longitudeDelta=0.01;
    region.span.latitudeDelta=0.01;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];

    ann = [[MapAnnotation alloc]init];
    ann.title = name;
    ann.subtitle = type;
    ann.coordinate=region.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
    [ann release];

    self.navigationItem.title=@"Map";
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

The map view also shows users location i think something is missing from the viewDidUnload method....

The MapAnnotation is a class that shows an annotation just holds a title and a subtitle.

i think the app keep tracking users location even if i leave the mapView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you set the delegate to nil, you did not call `[mapView release]`

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: sorry, you just saved my day! thanks a lot you rock man!!!!! Hours of coding i cant see the obvious!